# Is it worth adding 2x6s to allow thicker insulation in an attic?

Tags: insulation, attic

[image]

I am finishing my attic and I live in Southeast Michigan (zone 5). I have installed baffles and I have narrowed down my insulation choices to a few options.

Option 1 would be very similar to what is going on in this picture.  R21 batt with 2 inch rigid foam board.

Option 2 would be adding 2x6s to increase the depth of the rafters so I can use R38 insulation with foam board.

I'm leaning toward option 1.  I'm wondering if the added work and expense would be worth it for option 2.

Comment: I believe you've made this into an opinion question.  To determine whether or not it's worth it, you should do some analysis and compare the up-front cost of the added materials and labor vs. the energy costs down the road.

Comment: Batts are usually much more flame proof than foam(toxic fumes when burning), but are behind drywall or similar fire stops.

Comment: Despite this being opinion driven, it would be beneficial to know the location and specifically the climate conditions to have an informed answer.

Comment: Did you do the calculation with heat saving R21 vs R38

Comment: https://learnmetrics.com/insulation-r-value-chart-per-inch/

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what kind of foam board, but I'm going to assume something with R5 per inch, or R10 for a 2 inch foam board.

Option 1: R21+R10 = R31 => U value of 0.032

Option 2: R38+R10 = R48 => U value of 0.021

So on the surface, it looks like option 2 reduces heat loss ~30% compared to option 1.  But this is optimistic because it ignores the heat loss through the wood roof rafters.  So in reality the difference may only be 25%, or 20%.

But, let's look at this another way.  What if there was no roof insulation at all, and so assume an R (and U) value of 1 (roof sheathing, shingles, air film).  Then going from uninsulated to option 1 reduces your heat loss by 1-0.032 = 94.3%.  And going from uninsulated to option 2 reduces your heat loss by 1-0.021 = 97.9%.

So is it worth all the effort to reduce your heat loss from 94 .3% to 97.9%?

You would have to convert these two heat loss values into BTUs per hour and then based on your fuel source & costs, heating system efficiency, etc, to arrive at a dollar estimate of heating cost savings between option 2 and option 1.